# Como excluir a linha que gera automaticamente em uma gridView windowns form

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho uma `gridView` que assim que é populada com dados, sempre gera uma linha a mais. Como faço pra remover ?

**Obs. As colunas da grid são geradas dinamicamente.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
if (objPed.ConsultarPedido(Metodos.empresa, txtNumPedido.Text) > 0)
                    {
                        Cliente objCli = new Cliente();
                        Produtos objProd = new Produtos();
                        objCli.ConsultarCliente(objPed.PedCliente);
                        SetarPropriedades(objPed, objCli);
                        objPed.dtItensPedido = objPed.ConsultarItens();
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        dt.Columns.Add("Produtos");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Descrição");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Unid.");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Qtde.");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Vlr. Unit.");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Vlr. Desconto");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Vlr. Total");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Reorder");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Tipo Item");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Qtd.Dig.");
                        for (int i = 0; i < objPed.dtItensPedido.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            var tempRow = dt.NewRow();
                            dt.Rows.Add(tempRow);
                            dt.Rows[i]["Produtos"] = objPed.dtItensPedido.Rows[i]["ItPProduto"];
                            dt.Rows[i]["Descrição"] = objPed.dtItensPedido.Rows[i]["ItPDescrProd"];
                            dt.Rows[i]["Unid."] = objPed.dtItensPedido.Rows[i]["ItPUnidProd"];
                            dt.Rows[i]["Qtde."] = objPed.dtItensPedido.Rows[i]["ItPQtde"];
                            dt.Rows[i]["Vlr. Unit."] = objPed.dtItensPedido.Rows[i]["ItPrecoComp"];
                            dt.Rows[i]["Vlr. Desconto"] = objPed.dtItensPedido.Rows[i]["ItPDesconto"];
                            dt.Rows[i]["Vlr. Total"] = objPed.dtItensPedido.Rows[i]["ItPTotal"];
                            dt.Rows[i]["Reorder"] = objPed.dtItensPedido.Rows[i]["ItPReorder"];
                            dt.Rows[i]["Tipo Item"] = objPed.dtItensPedido.Rows[i]["ItPOrigem"];
                            dt.Rows[i]["Qtd.Dig."] = objPed.dtItensPedido.Rows[i]["ItPQtdeDig"]; //Qtd.Dig.
                        }
                        gridPedidos.DataSource = dt;
                        gridPedidos.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defina o valor da propriedade `AllowUserToAddRows` para `false`.

Se for fazer pelo modo *dedign*, procure pela propriedade na janela *properties* ao selecionar o controle.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou, em tempo de execução, faça isso

```
dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```